# Reading Cookie using bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, session-cookies, bookmarklet, cross-domain-policy

I am developing a **bookmarklet** that helps users share images. While authenticating the person, I need to read cookie set by domain: *www.xxx.com*.

The bookmarklet JavaScript is served by *bookmarklet.xxx.com* but since this JavaScript is rendered on the website on which bookmarklet is called, it only accessed the cookies of that site and not the ones set by *www.xxx.com*.

I have researched it and according to some answers at SO, this is a security issue and hence cookies from another domain can't be accessed.

I tried executing my scripts in a **hidden iframe** rendered by *www.xxx.com/iframe/iframe.html* and it did accessed the cookies but the problem is this script can't pass the value to my bookmarklet script. And I can't access the Iframe DOM which is another security issue.

Kindly suggest a suitable way so that I may solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to pass information from the iframe back to your page.

Sending the message:

```
windowReference.postMessage("The user is 'bob' and the password is 'secret'",
              "https://secure.example.net");
```

Reading the message

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event)
{
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.org:8080")
    return;

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Sure let me give it a try. And I'll really send you flowers if it works @epascarello ;)

Comment: This is good stuff but I think it has some serious compatibility issues with other browsers!

Comment: Just one last question. Is it possible if I was able to access unique browser hash or some unique finger print. You see my aim is to recognize a computer. If not through cookies, then is there any other way?

Comment: There are a bunch of libraries out there: https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs is one of them.